# Does series diverge

Tags: calculus

So, a series of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$, but $a_n=2n^{-1}$ if n is even, but $a_n=2^{-n}$ if $n$ is odd. So is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ diverge. I think it diverges, because it's the same as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=(-1)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Since all $a_n$ are positive, the series converges iff all subseries do, but the odd-$n$ subseries doesn't, as can be seen by comparing it with the harmonic series viz. $2/(2k-1)>1/k$.